# pagination in linq to sql into list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq to sql query that performs several joins in several tables to return a me list of data. The query works fine and returns me all the correct data. However, I have decided to add pagination in my data table, and have modified the below code a bit, so that not all data is fetched from the db at once.

The issue that I am having is how to add the data returned by the query inside the `var data` into the `allTrucks` list correctly ?

The exception that I am having is the following :

> Expression expected in Dynamic Linq

```
        List<TruckList> allTrucks = new List<TruckList>();


        try
        {
            using (PaginationContext _db = new PaginationContext())
            {

                var data = (from lad in _db.Jobs

                            join users in _db.Users on lad.Id equals users.Id into
                            ul
                            from users in ul.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            join ladAddressLoading in _db.Addresses.Where(a => a.TAD_N_ID == 1) on lad.Id equals ladAddressLoading.Id
                            join ladAddressDelivery in _db.Addresses.Where(a => a.TAD_N_ID == 2) on lad.Id equals ladAddressDelivery.Id
                            join countryLoading in _db.Countries on ladAddressLoading.Id equals countryLoading.Id
                            join countryDelivery in _db.Countries on ladAddressDelivery.Id equals countryDelivery.Id
                            join volume in _db.Measurements on lad.Id equals volume.Id

                            select new
                            {
                                Coordinator = users == null ? "No User" : users.FirstName + " " + users.LastName,
                                Volume = ladAddressLoading.VolumeTotal,
                                DeliveryCountry = countryDelivery.ISO2,
                                DeliveryDate = ladAddressDelivery.From,
                                LoadingCountry = countryLoading.ISO2,
                                LoadingDate = ladAddressLoading.From,

                            }).AsEnumerable()
                      .Select(x => new TruckList()
                      {

                          Coordinator = x.Coordinator,
                          Volume = x.Volume,
                          Delivery = x.DeliveryCountry + " - " + x.DeliveryDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                          Loading = x.LoadingCountry + " - " + x.LoadingDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),

                      });


                allTrucks.AddRange(data);

                totalRows = allTrucks.Count;


                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchVal))
                {
                    // filter
                    allTrucks = allTrucks.Where(x => x.FileID.ToLower().Contains(searchVal.ToLower())).ToList<TruckList>();
                }

                totalRowsAfterFilter = allTrucks.Count;

                // sorting

                allTrucks = allTrucks.OrderBy(sortColumnName + " " + sortDirection).ToList<TruckList>();

                // paging 

                allTrucks = allTrucks.Skip(start).Take(length).ToList<TruckList>();
```

How can I assign the `linq-to-sql` directly to the `List<TruckList>` directly ? 
Could someone advise a better approach of doing this ? Please help.

Comment: Use ToList() at end of query.  You do not need ToList<TruckList>().  The end of the .Select() requires the ToList(), or AddRange(data.ToList()).

Comment: Its asking me `Expression expected` at `allTrucks = allTrucks.OrderBy(sortColumnName + " " + sortDirection).ToList<TruckList>();`

Can you please help ?

Comment: I don't like using 'var' except when necessary it make debugging difficult.  Change 'var data' to List<TruckList>.  Then your .Select end with .ToList().  Then make OrderBy just end with .ToList().

Answer (score 1):

Break into two queries.  The variable data is not a TruckList.  See code below

```
                   var data = from lad in _db.Jobs

                                join users in _db.Users on lad.Id equals users.Id into ul
                                from users in ul.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                join ladAddressLoading in _db.Addresses.Where(a => a.TAD_N_ID == 1) on lad.Id equals ladAddressLoading.Id
                                join ladAddressDelivery in _db.Addresses.Where(a => a.TAD_N_ID == 2) on lad.Id equals ladAddressDelivery.Id
                                join countryLoading in _db.Countries on ladAddressLoading.Id equals countryLoading.Id
                                join countryDelivery in _db.Countries on ladAddressDelivery.Id equals countryDelivery.Id
                                join volume in _db.Measurements on lad.Id equals volume.Id

                                select new
                                {
                                    Coordinator = users == null ? "No User" : users.FirstName + " " + users.LastName,
                                    Volume = ladAddressLoading.VolumeTotal,
                                    DeliveryCountry = countryDelivery.ISO2,
                                    DeliveryDate = ladAddressDelivery.From,
                                    LoadingCountry = countryLoading.ISO2,
                                    LoadingDate = ladAddressLoading.From,

                                };



                    List<TruckList> trucks = data.Select(x => new TruckList()
                    {

                            Coordinator = x.Coordinator,
                            Volume = x.Volume,
                            Delivery = x.DeliveryCountry + " - " + x.DeliveryDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                            Loading = x.LoadingCountry + " - " + x.LoadingDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),

                    });


                    allTrucks.AddRange(trucks);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just like the exception says -- `.OrderBy` expects an `Expression` and you are passing a `string`.

```
allTrucks = allTrucks.OrderBy(sortColumnName + " " + sortDirection).ToList<TruckList>();
```

What it should be is something like

```
allTrucks = allTrucks.OrderBy(truck => truck.SomeProp).ToList();
```